# How to Distinct three column in one table And display it with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I Have a problem. Here's my code in PHP:

```
    $commentcall = pg_query("SELECT WSalamPembuka,WKonfirmasiNamaCust,WVerifikasiData ,WKemampuanBertanya ,WProductKnowledge ,WSolusi,WAlternativeSolusi,WSistemPelaporan,WEmpati,WResponsif,WRamahSopan,WPercayaDiri,WHoldCall,WOfferHelp,WPenutup
    FROM call
    WHERE 
    inputdate >='$start' AND inputdate<='$end' AND Agentname LIKE '$agen'");   

 while($result2=pg_fetch_row($commentcall))
        {
            for($x=1;$x<=15;$x++)
                {
                  if(($result2[$x]) != "" )
                    {
                       echo "<tr>
                       <td align=\"center\" style=\"border:1px solid      grey;width:55%\">",$result2[$x],"</td></tr>";
                    } 
                }
        }
```

And Here's my QUERY in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT
 WSalamPembuka,
 WKonfirmasiNamaCust,
 WVerifikasiData ,
 WKemampuanBertanya ,
 WProductKnowledge ,
 WSolusi,
 WAlternativeSolusi,
 WSistemPelaporan,
 WEmpati,
 WResponsif,
 WRamahSopan,
 WPercayaDiri,
 WHoldCall,
 WOfferHelp,
 WPenutup
FROM call
WHERE 
    inputdate ='02/12/2015' AND Agentname LIKE 'vita'
```

And The PostgreSQL Output would be like below : 
[image]

So I want to show it like below, but without have to show again the same data.

[image]

You can see that object "solusi" was shown twice because the database has two data "solusi".

Any help? Thankyou

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand the problem, you want to select only unique values?

Comment: 1. Store dates using a date data type

Comment: @Epodax Yes it's. You can see the table a little bit weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify you PostgrSQL query to aggragete columns for each row into `ARRAY` and then do `unnest` (which will expand an array to a set of rows) and `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        unnest(
             ARRAY[WSalamPembuka,
                 WKonfirmasiNamaCust,
                 WVerifikasiData ,
                 WKemampuanBertanya ,
                 WProductKnowledge ,
                 WSolusi,
                 WAlternativeSolusi,
                 WSistemPelaporan,
                 WEmpati,
                 WResponsif,
                 WRamahSopan,
                 WPercayaDiri,
                 WHoldCall,
                 WOfferHelp,
                 WPenutup]
        )
FROM call
WHERE 
    inputdate ='02/12/2015' AND Agentname LIKE 'vita'
```

Becasue that change the query alone returned "one-clumn" list to you need to change your php code and remove second loop `for($x=1;$x<=15;$x++)`.

Comment: Thankyou. Ya your solution it works in my PostgreSQL but in PHP, It has not shown up.. Have you another solution? or am i wrong?

Comment: It's not working because in PHP you assume that row has 15 columns, but from my answer row has only one column. Change line `for($x=1;$x<=15;$x++)` to `for($x=1;$x<=count($result2);$x++)` or even remove that loop at all.

Comment: Thankyou. Finally i already removed that loop at all. and it works. :D